# C# serializer/deserializer with same functionality as XStream in java

Tags: java, c#, xml, serialization, xstream

I need to accomplish very simple task: serialize and deserialize object hierarchy.

I've tried `XMLSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `NetDataContractSerializer` but nothing seems to work, there is always some problem.

`XMLSerializer` is bad because it requires all properties to be public. 
(Net)DataContractSerializer(s) are bad because it's always missing some metadata - but there are no metadata when user creates XML.

So how would you solve this task? Consider classes:

```
class A {
    private B instanceB;
    private int integerValue;

    ... getters/setters
}

class B {
    private List<C> cInstanceList;
    private string stringValue; 
    ... getters/setters
}

class C {
    ... some other properties
    ... getters/setters
}
```

and user input:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <cInstanceList>
      <C>
        <someproperties>val</someproperties>
      </C>
      <C>
        <someproperties>differentVal</someproperties>
      </C>
    </cInstanceList>
    <strigValue>lalala<stirngValue>
  </B>
  <integerValue>42</integerValue>
</A>
```

What `DataContractors` missing is metadata like "Type" or "Namespace" etc. `XStream` doesn't need that. I know the type of deserializing object, so I need to write function:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string xml);
```

my wanted use case:

```
var myDeserializedObject = Deserialize<A>(inputString);
```

What am I doing wrong? Would you solve it differently?

Comment: O and I forgot you DON'T USE GETTER AND SETTERS IN C# YOU USE PROPERTIES!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No serializer will fix typing mistakes ;). this worked for me using DataContractSerializer
XML (text.xml)

```
<A>
  <B>
    <cInstanceList>
      <C>

      </C>
      <C>
      </C>
    </cInstanceList>
    <stringValue>lalala</stringValue>
  </B>
  <integerValue>42</integerValue>
</A>
```

Classes

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
    class A
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "B")]
        private B instanceB;
        [DataMember(Name = "integerValue")]
        private int integerValue;

        public A(B instanceB, int integerValue)
        {
            this.instanceB = instanceB;
            this.integerValue = integerValue;
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    class B
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "cInstanceList")]
        private List<C> cInstanceList;

        [DataMember(Name = "stringValue")]
        private string stringValue;

        public B(List<C> cInstanceList, string stringValue)
        {
            this.cInstanceList = cInstanceList;
            this.stringValue = stringValue;
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    class C
    {
    }
```

Read

```
var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(A));
using (Stream reader = File.OpenRead("text.xml"))
{
    var result = (A)dcs.ReadObject(reader);
}
```

If you write it will add the xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" but won't make a difference you could remove it if you really need to.

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to have there also interface? 

Consider class D which has same interface as C. Instead of List<C>, could be there List<IMyInterface> so user could do something like: 

<myInstenceList>
 <C></C>
 <D></D>
<...>

?

Comment: Yes you could by making a custom [DataContractResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358759%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Don't forget to marl it as answered if this all you needed.

Comment: O you might want to look at XElement and XDocument they are super nice to use and will give you full control of object creation.